# Optimal policy finding with given constraint

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, functional-data-analysis

I'm trying to solve for the optimal policy function $h^*(x)$ over the domain of all policy functions $u_t = h(x_t)$ for the following problem.
\begin{equation}
\min_{h(x)} \, \mathbb{E}[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \, f(x_t,u_t)]
\end{equation}
where $f(x_t,u_t) = x_t^2u_t^2$ and subject to the following constraints
\begin{equation}
x_{k+1} = g(x_k,u_k,\epsilon_k) \forall k 
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon_k$ is the stochastic noise that can attain values from a finite discrete set
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r=0}^{N}u_r \geq M
\end{equation}
Can someone suggest methods to solve for the optimal policy function $u_t = h^*(x_t)$ with the given constraints as described above?